# Trigger new keyboard event with CapsLock from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jasmine, jestjs

I have a simple function that checks if CapsLock was on input

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.getModifierState("CapsLock")) {
       console.log('CapsLock is on')
       } else {
         console.log('Capslock is off')
       }
  });
```

To test the function I tried to trigger it this way:

```
  document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key:'A', capsLockKey: true}));
```

But it's not working

How can I trigger new Keyboard Event with CapsLock property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution on [W3C page](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#dom-eventmodifierinit-modifiercapslock)

```
document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key:'A', modifierCapsLock: true}));
```